# Rotation around a point causes weird glitches in THREE.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, three.js, rotation, transform

Every element from my scene is made of a chain of 3 `Object3D`s. The order parent-to-child is `cellPivot -> modifier -> setup`

`setup`'s purpose is to permanently align a loaded object by resizing / giving some padding that must always be there. It is not supposed to be changed once set

`modifier`'s purpose is to actually perform the real transformation on the object

`cellPivot`'s purpose is to allow me to drag `modifier` into a cell grid

An example why all this is needed: let's say I have a vertical door in an orthographic perspective that I wanna fit in a 1x1 space, so I give some padding on the x-axis to align the door in the center, similar to the picture below where the orange block is the door

[image]

Since I want to move this in any cell in the map, I use `cellPivot`'s position to decide where. I can't use right away `modifier` since sometimes I wanna rotate the model inside the cell, which requires to modify both position and rotation (since my models are not built around (0, 0, 0), but along +X and +Z)

I have succesfully managed to rotate these doors by rotating `modifier` around the center of the model (which acts as a pivot). Here's the functions that does the rotation:

```js
three.Object3D.prototype.pivot = function(pivot, f) {
  pivot = lib.VecToVector3(three, pivot); // just a conversion between libs
  this.position.sub(pivot);
  f(this);
  this.position.add(pivot);
  return this;
};
three.Object3D.prototype.pivotRotate = function(pivot, axis, theta, rotational = false, abs = false) {
  if(abs)
    theta -= this.rotation.y; /// not good, handles only y
  this.pivot(pivot, () => this.position.applyAxisAngle(axis, theta));
  if(rotational)
    this.rotateOnAxis(axis, theta);
  return this;
};
```

The line that rotates the door and works:

```js
this.o3d.userData.modifier.pivotRotate(this.o3d.userData.center, new three.Vector3(0, 1, 0), this.rot, true);
```

I'm now trying to do something similar with the player too. I record what keys are pressed, I calculate the normal of the vector of desired direction (if I press W and D I'll get (1, 1), if I press just W I'll get (0, 1)), after which I use the following line to detect the angle at which the user wanna move:

```js
Math.atan2(-normal[1], normal[0]);
```

I have already tested that the angle is correct. On top of that, the codebase before "rotating around a pivot" used the same code and it worked fine

Everytime there's actually a direction the user wanna go, I'll run the following line:

```js
this.o3d.userData.modifier.pivotRotate(this.o3d.userData.center, new three.Vector3(0, 1, 0), Math.atan2(-normal[1], normal[0]), true, true);
```

If the user just keeps a key pressed, then `abs` will make sure that no visible rotation is made (since `theta` will be `0`)

Here's the problem: everytime I press A, be it in combination with W or S or not, the character will rotate like insane. I put after the line from above the following code to see what's happening:

```js
com.log(new three.Euler().setFromQuaternion(this.o3d.userData.setup.getWorldQuaternion(new three.Quaternion())));
```

I'm getting this:

[image]

As you can see, x and z are reaching -pi, and y bouces back and forth. This does not happen for any other combination that does not contain key A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update after 2 days:

I have rewrote my function like this:
[image]

I got these in console while trying to move in the problematic positions:
[image]

As it can be seen in the first log, my target is at rotation `0` and is going for `-2.35...`, but `rotAfterRot` is showing weird results..: `-pi` and `-.78...`

This is the result of running `this.rotateOnAxis(axis, theta)`. I have changed this exact line with `this.rotation.y += theta`. Now everything is working as it should be: no weird `-pi` and `rotAfterRot.y` is actually `theta`

My guess is that `rotateOnAxis` is also counting other features of the object, like position, but still can't figure how it spits that `-pi`